# Same docker image run on different machine results in different container

Tags: docker

I am running the same docker image `X` on two different machines `hostA` & `hostB`, but when the two containers start the one in `hostB` is missing some files (specifically 2 node modules, but the parent directory exists-empty).

I tried to force remove the image from both hosts and then re-pull and retry which lead to the same result. Also the containers do not mount any volumes related to these files.

I rebuilt image `X` (from the same revision of course) locally and pushed the snapshot build to the local repository. Now this locally built image seems to be working fine on both machines.

Yet after two days of searching I haven't figured out why or how this could happen?

I expected such a behavior to not be possible using docker, though I'm new to docker and might be missing something. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Someone posted a similar question about a Tomcat build with some jar files that weren't consistent between a linux docker host and people using docker for mac, I can't find the question though. Are hostA and hostB the same platform/versions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use bind mount when starting your container? I guess bind mount would help to persist your data on your data on local even of the container is removed. Try running your container as below:

`docker container run -d --name node-v $(pwd):/usr/share/local <container name>`

Comment: The idea is that there should me no volume mounted. So the command was `docker container run <container name>:<version>`, yet this would yield different results on different hosts